# how to display only bluetooth name in address

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hi in the below code displaying the Bluetooth device names.
suppose there is no name for the device default it was displaying the Bluetooth address.

Now my doubt is want to display only Bluetooth name for every time. Sometime Bluetooth name is displaying and sometimes Bluetooth address is displaying.

can any one please help me want to show every time Bluetooth name.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final DeviceListViewHolder viewHolder = (DeviceListViewHolder) holder;
        if (mDevices != null) {
            BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = mDevices.get(position);
            if (bluetoothDevice != null) {
                String deviceName = bluetoothDevice.getName();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(deviceName)) {
                    viewHolder.mDeviceName.setText(deviceName);
                } else {
                    viewHolder.mDeviceName.setText(bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: that is exactly what your code is doing. You have implemented it to show name when it is available and show address otherwise

Comment: but everytime want to show only name

Comment: not every device has name. And it is not always available. Therefore you can't

Comment: Isn't your code is written to display address if the name doesn't exist? Check your if-else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Every Bluetooth device will not have a name. But yes address will always be there. So, make sure first whether your Bluetooth device is having a name if not then you can display some default name instead displaying address.